# Why is there no vertical space between adsense and input group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I have a simple page that utilizes bootstrap.  There are 3 divs within the bootstrap "container" div:

1. Title
2. Responsive Adsense
3. Ajax form control

I want some vertical space between the ad and the form control.  However, whatever I do, the adsense ad is flush against the form control.

I have tried using bootstrap div classes (e.g. below is my-1 I think is supposed to create a top and bottom vertical margins) and manually adding 
's (sorry I'm out of ideas and don't have much experience with bootstrap or adsense)

```
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <h3>name check</h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-9999999991673999"
         data-ad-slot="9954999999"
         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="my-1">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" id="btn-name" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-check">check</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle or a stack snippet?

Comment: What version of bootstrap you're using? Class `my-1` works only in v4

Comment: @fen1x - yes this the problem: mismatch between the my version (3.3.7) and the docs I was reading (v4).

Comment: @MatthiasS. thx - I was not aware of those tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add some css

```
.my-1 {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Or you can add inline css:

```
<div style="margin-top:1em;">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" id="btn-name" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-check">check</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works too and I would have done this next had I not been informed of the version mismatch.